Looking for guidance on wall mounted faucet spout length
Renovating a bathroom and was hoping for some guidance re: the minimum necessary spout reach beyond the back edge of the sink should be.  Using Kohler Purist wall mounted faucet, which has a 6.75" spout reach and a 35-degree angle at the spout output.  I haven't purchased the sink yet, and I have some flexibility in placement (e.g., relative to the typical 4" setback from front edge of decking).
But I don't know how much extension over the sink bowl is desirable/necessary, especially given the angle at the end of the faucet.  I know that ideally the water should hit the sink drain, but not sure how to calculate that given the spout angle.
Any guidance would be much appreciated.  Thanks!

The angle of the water leaving the faucet will be straight down at low flow, so unless you like dripping behind the sink every time you turn it off or on, if should be over the sink.
There's nothing particularly ideal (nor does code have anything to say on the subject) about the water stream hitting the drain opening. There should be enough room to rinse your hands in the stream without splashing water out of the sink, in a practical sense, though I don't believe there's code guidance on that, either.
